# ValidatorEngine.Validate returns null (no error) if configured its ValidatorMode.UseExternal

Tags: validation, nhibernate-validator

i am integrating nhibernate validator into my application and and everything is fine with attributes 
but as soon as I create *.nhv.xml files and move my validation rules there (as embedded resource)

```
ValidatorEngine.Validate(entity)
```

returns wrong (actually nothing and my `InvalidValue[]` collection is empty

I appropriate any comment/advise

Answer (score 2):

The problem was because of configuration part of the nhibernate validator
first the

```
NHibernateSharedEngineProvider
```

should get assigned to

```
NHibernate.Validator.Cfg.Environment.SharedEngineProvider
```

then
we have to call the current engine's

```
Configure
```

not a new instance 
of `ValidatorEngine`
so the full configuration section may look like this:

```
           var provider = new NHibernateSharedEngineProvider();
           NHibernate.Validator.Cfg.Environment.SharedEngineProvider = provider;
```

var nhvConfiguration = new FluentConfiguration();
       nhvConfiguration
              .SetDefaultValidatorMode(ValidatorMode.UseExternal)
              .Register(Assembly.Load("assembley name")
                  .ValidationDefinitions())
              .IntegrateWithNHibernate
                      .ApplyingDDLConstraints()
                      .And
                      .RegisteringListeners();

        var validatorEngine = NHibernate.Validator.Cfg.Environment.SharedEngineProvider.GetEngine();
        validatorEngine.Configure(nhvConfiguration);